# Why "HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit" writes 2 bytes of data in each loop

Tags: i2c, master-slave, hal, stm32f4

I'm using HAL library for stm32f4 (V1.7.1) and trying to understand how HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit works. This function transmits a "master to slave" packet on SDA line. 
In the stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.c code after sending slave address there is a loop (`while(hi2c->XferSize > 0U)`) that sends bytes which we want to be transmitted to slave. This loop works until all bytes are transmitted. But there is a question that "why the function wants to transmit **TWO** bytes in each loop?" There is an IF in loop (`if((__HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_BTF) == SET) && (hi2c->XferSize != 0U))`) that checks if the previous byte is currently transferred then send the the next byte!
I don't know what is the reason of existing this IF when in the next loop other bytes can be transmitted?!

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t 
DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
{
  uint32_t tickstart = 0x00U;

  /* Init tickstart for timeout management*/
  tickstart = HAL_GetTick();

  if(hi2c->State == HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
  {
    /* Wait until BUSY flag is reset */
    if(I2C_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_BUSY, SET, 
I2C_TIMEOUT_BUSY_FLAG, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
    {
      return HAL_BUSY;
    }

/* Process Locked */
__HAL_LOCK(hi2c);

/* Check if the I2C is already enabled */
if((hi2c->Instance->CR1 & I2C_CR1_PE) != I2C_CR1_PE)
{
  /* Enable I2C peripheral */
  __HAL_I2C_ENABLE(hi2c);
}

/* Disable Pos */
hi2c->Instance->CR1 &= ~I2C_CR1_POS;

hi2c->State     = HAL_I2C_STATE_BUSY_TX;
hi2c->Mode      = HAL_I2C_MODE_MASTER;
hi2c->ErrorCode = HAL_I2C_ERROR_NONE;

/* Prepare transfer parameters */
hi2c->pBuffPtr    = pData;
hi2c->XferCount   = Size;
hi2c->XferOptions = I2C_NO_OPTION_FRAME;
hi2c->XferSize    = hi2c->XferCount;

/* Send Slave Address */
if(I2C_MasterRequestWrite(hi2c, DevAddress, Timeout, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
{
  if(hi2c->ErrorCode == HAL_I2C_ERROR_AF)
  {
    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hi2c);
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }
  else
  {
    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hi2c);
    return HAL_TIMEOUT;
  }
}

/* Clear ADDR flag */
__HAL_I2C_CLEAR_ADDRFLAG(hi2c);

while(hi2c->XferSize > 0U)
{
  /* Wait until TXE flag is set */
  if(I2C_WaitOnTXEFlagUntilTimeout(hi2c, Timeout, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
  {
    if(hi2c->ErrorCode == HAL_I2C_ERROR_AF)
    {
      /* Generate Stop */
      hi2c->Instance->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;
      return HAL_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
      return HAL_TIMEOUT;
    }
  }

  /* Write data to DR */
  hi2c->Instance->DR = (*hi2c->pBuffPtr++);
  hi2c->XferCount--;
  hi2c->XferSize--;

  if((__HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_BTF) == SET) && (hi2c->XferSize != 0U))
  {
    /* Write data to DR */
    hi2c->Instance->DR = (*hi2c->pBuffPtr++);
    hi2c->XferCount--;
    hi2c->XferSize--;
  }

  /* Wait until BTF flag is set */
  if(I2C_WaitOnBTFFlagUntilTimeout(hi2c, Timeout, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
  {
    if(hi2c->ErrorCode == HAL_I2C_ERROR_AF)
    {
      /* Generate Stop */
      hi2c->Instance->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;
      return HAL_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
      return HAL_TIMEOUT;
    }
  }
}

/* Generate Stop */
hi2c->Instance->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;

hi2c->State = HAL_I2C_STATE_READY;
hi2c->Mode = HAL_I2C_MODE_NONE;

/* Process Unlocked */
__HAL_UNLOCK(hi2c);

return HAL_OK;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's an optimization to take full advantage of the 1-byte buffer. Overall, two bytes can be in progress: one byte in the shift register and one byte in the buffer. So if the shift register is idle, the byte written to DR immediately goes into the shift register and the buffer is ready to accept another byte (again written to DR). Most likley, it will only write 2 bytes in the first loop iteration and after the loop has been delayed by a handled interrupt.

Comment: @Codo
Thanks!
So you mean the IF condition checks "if shift register is not empty and DR is empty" then write a byte in DR? And existing this IF makes transmitting 2 bytes of data faster than repeating transmission in the next WHILE?

Comment: Yes, about as you describe.